# Macros in excel: Find Similarities between two columns and fill the coincidences

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro that search in a column and find coincidences with the other column the fill it with yellow to recongnize it.

Column A 1137 Rows
Colimn B 537 Rows

Fill with yelllow in A the values found in B

I thinks its like

```
For i = 1 To i = 1137

    For n = 1 To n = 592

        If Cells(A, i) = Cells(L, n) Then

        Cells(i, A).Value = Fill

        End If

    Next

Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use conditional formatting instead of a macro?  Picture's worth more than my typing...

[image]

Original post didn't have a negative result so I added one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this VERY easily with conditional formatting!

Just select all of column A where you want the data to be highlighted and, then:

1. Select Conditional Formatting
2. New Rule
3. Use a Formula to determine which cell to format
4. Put in the following conditional format rule:

   `=ISNUMBER(MATCH($A1,$B$1:$B$537,0))`
5. Set the fill color to yellow

And that should do it!